# How to add and remove active class in navigation in react js

Tags: reactjs

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <Link to={'/home'}>
      Home
    </Link>
  </li>
  <li>
    <Link to={'/story'}>
      About us
    </Link>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I have above navigation tab in reactjs and I would like to toggle active class on click between links. I have been go through on various stacks but not able to find proper answer for above scenerio.

Comment: And what have you tried to achieve this? What exactly is not working with your approach?

Comment: Hi Nico haase, Thanks for look into the matter, simply I would like to achieve add and remove active class on click of my links using join and push method in reactjs, as it happens on any regular website link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One can use [`react-router/web#NavLink`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/NavLink) instead [`react-router/web#Link`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Link).

Attach the **class** that you want to use as a **active class** using `activeClassName` property of `NavLink`.

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <NavLinkto={'/home'} activeClassName="selected">Home</NavLink>
  </li>
  <li>
    <NavLinkto={'/story'} activeClassName="selectedSec">About us</NavLink>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Hi Riyaj, Thanks for Answer.
This works absolutely fine for me, previously I was trying to do it using join and push method which seems somehow complex as it have props and stats also included.

Comment: @AbhishekBhatore glad to help u.upvote and accept it if its working for you